# winsock : bluetooth client-server not connecting

Tags: visual-c++, bluetooth, winsock

I have written a small bluetooth server and client progrem using winsock

I am not able to figure out why the client is not getting connected to the server. Both are running in different pcs and 
both are paired through bluetooth.

The server code is

```
void server()
{
    SOCKET server_socket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM), new_socket;
    if (server_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "socket creation failed...Error code : " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        return;
    }
    cout << "socket created" << endl;
    SOCKADDR_BTH sa, sa2;
    int channel = 0, len=sizeof(sa2);
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof(SOCKADDR_BTH));
    sa.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    sa.port = channel & 0xff;

    //bind
    if (bind(server_socket, (SOCKADDR *)&sa, sizeof(sa)))
    {
        cout << "Binding failed...Error code : " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(server_socket);
        Sleep(2000);
        return;
    }
    cout << "binding done" << endl;
    cout << "\nWaiting for client" << endl;
    listen(server_socket, 3);
    new_socket = accept(server_socket, (sockaddr *)&sa2, &len);
    cout<<"connection accepted";
}
```

The client code is

```
void client()
{
    SOCKET client_socket = socket(AF_BTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTHPROTO_RFCOMM);
    int channel = 0;
    BTH_ADDR bt_addr;
    char* server_address = "34:02:86:26:c1:62";
    if (client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "socket creation failed...Error code : " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        return;
    }
    cout << "socket created" << endl;
    if (str2ba(server_address, &bt_addr) == 1)
    {
        cout << "address conversion error..." << endl;
        Sleep(2000);
        return;
    }
    SOCKADDR_BTH sa;
    sa.addressFamily = AF_BTH;
    sa.port = channel & 0xff;
    sa.btAddr = bt_addr;
    cout << "\nconnecting..." << endl;
    if (connect(client_socket, (sockaddr *)&sa, sizeof(sockaddr)))
    {
        cout << "Error in connecting...Error code : " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(client_socket);
        Sleep(2000);
        return;
    }
    cout << "\nConnected" << endl;
    Sleep(2000);
}

int str2ba(char *str_bt_addr, BTH_ADDR *bt_addr)//for converting string to bluetooth address
{
    unsigned int addr[6];
    if (sscanf_s(str_bt_addr, "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x", 
    &addr[0], &addr[1], &addr[2], &addr[3], &addr[4], &addr[5]) != 6)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    *bt_addr = 0;
    BTH_ADDR tmpaddr;
    int i;
    for (i = 0;i < 6;++i)
    {
        tmpaddr = (BTH_ADDR)(addr[i] & 0xff);
        *bt_addr = ((*bt_addr) << 8) + tmpaddr;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Why are these not getting connected? What am I missing?
Please help me.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In my short Bluetooth experience, the problem is normally somewhere in the SOCKADDR_BTH declarations.

I hard coded the MAC Address of each Endpoint: "38:2D:E8:B9:FA:EB" in Hex

```
RemoteEndPoint.btAddr = BTH_ADDR(0x382DE8B9FAEB);
```

Also make sure your Ports are the same on each Endpoint, I used:

```
RemoteEndPoint.port = 0;
```

and

```
LocalEndpoint.port = 0;
```

I have some code here: [C++ WinSock Bluetooth Connection - AT Command - Error Received](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098557/c-winsock-bluetooth-connection-at-command-error-received) where I have an issue also.

Bluetooth is not as easy as some may think, thus the lack of answers received by the OP's